# What chat.meta.SO and not chat.SO.com?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

SeverFault has Meta.SF and Chat.SF.
StackOverflow has Meta.SO and Chat.Meta.SO.

SF Chat, if I understand correctly, uses SF login.
SO Chat uses Meta.SO login.

Took me awhile to realize the differences.

Is there a reason to have two different setups?

Seems confusing to me. I'm still new to SO, and this is my first post to M.SO. So although I have the points (barely) on SO, I can't chat because the points for chatting on SO are from Meta.

I understand Chat is in Beta. So it may just be trying different things. Just hadn't seen anything explaining the difference in hierarchy.

Comment: simply: because the chat is for meta and meta is for stackoverflow!

Comment: SO will get it's own chat in due course - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/ and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/chat-now-in-public-beta/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/server-fault-chat-now-available/

> chat.serverfault.com is still a public beta, but we’re rapidly closing in on release status. I expect we’ll begin a fairly aggressive rollout of chat across all sites within 4 weeks or so — though do be advised that stackoverflow.com will be the last site to get it because of its immense volume.

Answer (score 2):

What they said :)

chat.meta was/is our initial playpen, to gather feedback in beta from the MSO users who are generally pretty patient and understanding (helpful, even) if things aren't perfect.

We've avoided chat.stackoverflow only because it is the biggest of the sites. I think we'll get there fairly soon, though.

chat.serverfault is now in, so the rollout has begun.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, there will soon be a chat.stackoverflow.com... It's just because it's only just now leaving beta... From [the blog post where chat was announced](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/chat-now-in-public-beta/):

> This is a permanent public beta,
> meaning chat is now live on one site
> in our network … forever. We plan to
> roll out out chat on more sites in
> about 4 weeks, assuming the public
> beta goes reasonably well

ServerFault's chat used to be a room under chat.meta.stackoverflow.com, and [only got moved to chat.serverfault.com today](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/1097124976/live-chat-for-server-fault).

EDIT: [Here's more information from today's blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/server-fault-chat-now-available/).